# What are examples of child-friendly rap?

Tags: music

My 10-year old son is interested in hip-hop dances. When I asked him about whether he'd like to write rap songs, he said it would interest him.

I want to take a piece of rap lyrics and then show him, how it's structured and how the rhymes are connected to the beats.

The only problem I have is finding child-friendly rap. My favorite is Eminem, but I'm not aware of any of his songs suitable for a child this age.

Are there any songs, which

1. have the typical rap structure and
2. are suitable for a 10-year old child?

Note: I intend to create something like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4QOGxpt3a8), but without the F, M*F and the B words. I'm not looking for such videos, I'm looking for "clean" rap songs, for which I could do such video myself.

**Update 1:** Mase seems to be clean, at least in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adg6iEz3-Ow).

**Update 2:** As well as Scroobius Pip's [Get Better](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEitrZU-nCw).

Comment: I'm afraid this is going to end up a long list of songs — could we rephrase it maybe, something like "where can I find songs" or "how would I screen songs"?

Comment: @Erica I added a note. Please tell me, if it's OK now.

Comment: Consider Scroobius Pip. His work has some pretty strong positive messages, the lyrics are pretty deep and if it contains any strong language (it might, but I doubt it) he'll learn APPROPRIATE use of strong words :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DJ Jazzy Jeff and the Fresh Prince!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJ_Jazzy_Jeff_%26_The_Fresh_Prince) You may well know him better as Will Smith or the Fresh Prince of Bel Air.

You can get all the songs on iTunes or just open up youtube. It's the first rap I listened to when I was a kid and it's still fun.